# How to bypass current sensor (ACS712) default 2.5V voltage output in buck/boost converter PCB

Tags: pcb, diodes, current-measurement, debugging, buck-boost

I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with the most practical fix for my buck/boost converter PCB. To give a bit of an overview, I'm using a current sensor to read the current value through an inductor, that output is fed through an op-amp to amplify the signal, and then that is finally fed into comparators that controls a circuit to switch two MOSFETs on/off to maintain the inductor current between a min and max value.

In short, the circuit goes: current sense -> op-amp -> comparators -> MOSFET driver.

This worked well in simulations, however, on my PCB, the current sensor's default voltage output when it doesn't sense a current is 2.5V. Because of this extremely high voltage, the value goes right past the comparators and keeps one MOSFET on, without ever switching the other. The normal voltage values that the current sensor should output is between 0-500 mV. I only need to get past the initial default 2.5V on the output by pulling the line to GND briefly (to get the other MOSFET to turn on and allow current flow to the inductor) to get my circuit to start working.

I've brainstormed two ways to go about this, but I would love to get additional feedback.

1. Find a diode with a forward voltage greater than 500 mV, and solder it directly to the output of the current sensor. This way, whenever the voltage on the line goes above 500 mV (would never get this high during normal operation), the diode will short straight to GND.
2. Use an additional comparator on the current sense output that pulls the line low whenever it detects 2.5V at the output and 2.5V on the other input pin. Since my PCB has already been fabricated, I would need to run about 8 wires that connect to this IC all over the board. Not ideal, but I think it will get the job done.

What are your thoughts? Thanks for all your help. I've included a link to the part I'm using below.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/allegro-microsystems/ACS712ELCTR-05B-T/1284593

[image]

Comment: I am pretty confused. Are you saying that when the sensor is putting out 2.5V with 0 amps, this is a stable but incorrect operational state? I feel like something could be done to your op-amp circuit to fix this. If you could post a schematic it might help.

Comment: @mkeith Sorry for the confusion, I've added a picture of what I'm working with here. According to the ACS712 datasheet, it states that quiescent output voltage will be Vcc/2 (Vcc = 5V in the circuit) when the primary current is zero. So, because the circuit is reliant on this output reading to switch the MOSFETs to charge the inductor, it's currently stuck at a state where Q2 stays on and Q1 stays off. I don't believe messing with the op-amp is a good idea because as soon as I can get past this default state, I'll need the gain to accurately control the inductor current between I_min and I_max

Comment: It seems odd is all. Without studying the circuit in detail it seems like you are trying to arrange for a window comparator. So you keep the current between two limits. But if, for any reason, the current should drop too low, the output does not end up in the correct state to increase current. So there is an undesired stable operation point at zero current and 2.5V out of the ACS712. Is that accurate?

Comment: Why don't you simulate what is the actual output response of your sensor and fiddle with your sim with offsets to make things work.

Comment: I still don't get it. I don't think it can ever work the way you have it. The only way for the output voltage of the ACS712 to be below 2.5V is for current to flow up from ground through the inductor. Isn't what you really want to do to subtract the 2.5V offset from the ACS 712? You can do that at the op-amp, I think.

Comment: The output of the ACS 712 is a linear ramp which is offset up from ground by 2.5V so that negative currents will be less than 2.5V and positive currents will be greater than 2.5V. Is it possible that you didn't realize that? Please don't take offense. We have a wide range of knowledge levels on this forum. It may well be that I am the one who is not getting it (I haven't really rolled up my sleeves to look at your circuit yet).

Comment: @mkeith Oh man.. You're correct. No offense taken. I missed this entirely and didn't notice the 2.5V offset on ACS712. Thank you for the help. I'll see what I can do with the op-amp and adjusting the comparator voltages to get it to function correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is a fundamental conceptual disconnect here. The ACS712 output is offset to mid-rail to facilitate reading voltage when the current can be either positivist or negative. The ACS product literature calls this "bipolar." Some ACS current sensors are unipolar (although they may be offset slightly above ground anyway).

It seems like your best bet to fix up your circuit will be to remove the 2.5V offset at the op-amp. Please note that the ACS devices are "ratiometric" meaning that the offset will be very close to mid-rail (VCC/2). So rather than use a precision 2.5V reference to generate that offset at your op-amp, you would want to use a voltage divider from the same VCC that powers the ACS712, if possible.